# Who is who after my directory is changed

Tags: c#

I would like to know if there any methods for me to record information of who have accessed and made any changes to my file in the file server ? 
This application is made for local use only, and I must use C#Express since I can't afford a professional or ultimate version. The C# Express doesn't have WCF enabled features at all. But I am not going to do anything related to web services. Thank you for your ideas.

Comment: Are these changes to be made via your program? Or is this program suppose to monitor normal file changes via windows file browsing. If its via your program, Have them logon and/or use their windows logon as an ID and store the ID of who carries out the given task.

Comment: FileSystemWatcher is a good start I would think... fairly easy to implement:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Comment: As @JohnBartels has stated, it is a good place to start.  Just be careful of trying to use the file while something is still writing to it.